# multiple columns crosstab layout

Tags: crystal-reports

how can I achieve below layout using a crosstab? Month in the top of the columns and columns below with their own names.[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the crosstab, added a formula that shows me the month name as column and the other fields as **summarized fields**. Then on **crosstab expert** ->  **Customized Style** tab, under columns section I selected my **grand totals**, checked **show labels** and **Horizontal** and was able to get the desired layout. Thanks @Ryan

Answer (score 0):

In the Cross-Tab Expert you can create groupings like this by just adding more columns (The outer-most groupings are those higher in the Column list). In your case, the first column of your Cross-Tab should be your record date with the option selected to print for each Month. Then just add the rest of your columns to your Cross-Tab as usual.